# extract text from links and insert in new sorted

Tags: windows

I have a single html file that's updated and generated frequently.  It's a list sorted by names and linked with html that contain numbers in the end like ...#835C or #717.

I would like to extract just the number (no letter) and insert it into a new html file sorted by the number but still linked with the original.

Can you help me make this chore an easy one, thanks?

Here is the file I shortened from the current count of 850.  The upper half is original and the lower is what I'd like extracted as an example.

http://selvan777.tripod.com/test/rin.htm

Thanks,
Selvan

Comment: Sorry, but 1. looking at your sample data, its' really hard tell what you want. 2. It would really help if you told us what programming environment/languages you have available (and tag this message with 1 OS and 1 language). 3. Include a sample of what you want the output to look like. Can you compress your html sample, so it only takes up 8-10 lines of text (without blank lines)? Good luck

Comment: original text= <a href="aqwg01.htm#426C">JANE, Mary</a> b.1962 / output text= <a href="aqwg01.htm#426C">426 Jane, Mary</a> b.1962 / I would like the output to have just the number in the a tag inserted before the name then have the page sorted by that number, currently 1-850. Some have the C in the number and some don't. I would prefer to leave it out. Thanks, Selvan.

Comment: When I said tag your msg with a language, I meant programming language. If you're using Windows, how do expect to process a file that is 'generated frequently'? What is generating the file ( part of your system?) or a remote server? Would this be 1 file that keeps getting bigger, OR do you hope to keep each day, or hour, or minutes changed file seperately? Do you know how to use Excel?

Comment: Sorry. It's Ancestral Quest (family tree web page wizard). For now, with just 850 people, it fits all in 1 file. It will surely expand to more as it grows. I do know how to use Excel but am not great at it, truth is I did try it but couldn't figure out how to mine just those numbers and I ended up doing one at a time and gave up. I do use BK Replace EM with 15 file sets in it that does all the customizing to every page each time I make an update but, sadly, it can't do this last thing.

Comment: If you don't access to Linux/Unix, I don't think I can help you. Also, it is very easy to edit your original post and add information that people (I) have asked for. Learn how to  use the formating options at the top of the edit page. Format the data as '{}' (code) and it will be easier for people to read. Note that you can see the results of your reformatting below the editor labeled something like 'Preview'. If you have to do this in Windows, then you have to pick a programming language (Excel should work) AND you need to tell people, via a tag that the programming language = (Excel?)'. GdLk

Comment: The Link has expired, if this is sti8ll a problem, update the link,